# Why can I pass a BOOL to a method that requires an NSInteger argument?

Tags: cocoa, xcode6

Why can I declare/define a method like this:

```
@interface Dog : NSObject

- (void) doStuff:(NSInteger)val;

@end
```

...

```
@implementation Dog

- (void) doStuff:(NSInteger)val {

    NSLog(@"arg was valid");

}

@end
```

...and call it like this:

```
Dog* mydog = [[Dog alloc] init];
[mydog doStuff:YES];  //=>arg was valid
```

I've read that BOOL is a typedef for a signed char.  Usually in Xcode6, if the types don't exactly match, I get all kinds of warnings that tell me to cast to the proper type, and Xcode will insert the casts for me if I click on the right spot.

Comment: Ahh.  *On 64-bit architectures, NSInteger and NSUInteger are defined as long and unsigned long, respectively.*   So the cast from signed char to long happens automatically?

Comment: Yup, no warning here:

    `signed char x = 104;
    NSLog(@"%c", x);  //=>h
    long y = x;
    NSLog(@"%ld", y); //=>104`

And no warnings going the other way: 
   `long y = 258;
    NSLog(@"%ld", y); //=>258
    
    signed char x = y;
    NSLog(@"%d", x); //=>2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the C family of languages - (Objective-)C(++) - the various boolean types (`BOOL`, `bool`, `_Bool`) are all classed as integer types. (`char` is also an integer type.)

Using a smaller integer type where a larger integer type is required is an implicit conversion, no cast is required.

Combine those and you can pass a `BOOL` as an `NSInteger`.

HTH

Comment: I made two mistakes: 1)I though NSInteger was an object 2) I could not remember from my C++ days that a char was an integer type.  However, your answer leaves my wondering why the example in my comment(under my answer) does not require a cast when converting a long to a char.

Comment: @7stud - I was being kind to C. Storing into a smaller unsigned type is defined to truncate, storing into a smaller signed type is implementation defined. C is barely a typed language.